# Very small font size in some samsung smartphones

Tags: css, smartphone

Client complaining that font size [in that site](https://mirlex.ee/reklaamiteenused) is very tiny. He is using Samsung A5 + Chrome. I can't figure out why... :( Tested in different simulators - no problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because of `em`-s

Comment: Please read - https://fvsch.com/code/css-locks/